# Can I have a SQL View which joins on certain criteria

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables. One is a list of telephone numbers from all around the world, there's around 13,0000 or so but the actual amount is not that important.

In my second table is a lookup with all the international dialling codes by country and the number of digits a phone number from that respective country may have - some countries may have differing lengths therefore more than 1 entry.

What I would like to do in SQL is somehow engineer it, so it can look at the start of the telephone number and the number of digits in the number and then attach the country of origin next to it

For example Table 1

Would have this entry - 0085222948599

And Table 2

Would have Hong Kong, 00852, 13 - this is the country, prefix and number length

So can I write something that says if a certain prefix and a certain length, add country to an additional column

I hope I've explained myself properly, not sure if this feasible or not. Hope you may be able to help me out

Thanks
Dan

Comment: Though your question already has proper explanation, you will get more answers when there is sample data and expected result properly displayed in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can -

```
SELECT * 
FROM Phones p
INNER JOIN Countries c ON LEN(p.Number) = c.NumberLength AND LEFT(p.Number, LEN(c.Prefix)) = c.Prefix
```

Comment: If I can understand thiis

Phones = being my first table which holds all the raw data,
Countries = being the list of countries in the lookup,
Number = being the phone number from the first table,
Number Length = self explanatory,
Prefix = self explanatory,

And I just change the relevant words for the table/column that they relate to - while leaving the lower case letters in their place?

Thanks

Comment: Yes Edward, That works perfectly, thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
SELECT Phone, Country
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Phone LIKE Prefix +'%' AND LEN(Phone) = NumberLength
```

Comment: Unfortunately Zohar that is only giving me 5 matches out of 13,000 which is far less than expected. So it's certainly working to some aspect but not quite how I need it. Appreciate your imput though

Comment: Well I suggest tou follow Prdp's advice and edit your question.